# Why is the function taking all the values?

Tags: python

I found a problem... When I am executing first function, it takes away the data from the csv file that I imported and uses it, that's why nothing is left for the other functions to execute... How to rectify this? 
If the second function is executed alone, it gives the desired results

CSV file has 3 rows,i.e., Voter id no., County, Candidate

```
import csv 
with open('election_data_1-2.csv') as file1:         
      reader1 = csv.reader(file1) 

      def total_votes(): 
           f1 = [vote1[0] for vote1 in reader1]
           print("The total number of voters are:",len(f1)-1)

      def unique_candidates(): 
           b = [] 
           for cd1 in reader1: 
                if cd1[2] == "Candidate"
                     None
                elif cd1[2] not in b: 
                     b.append(cd1[2]) 
           return ("\nThe candidates taking part in elections are",b)
      total_votes()
      unique_candidates()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result with the second function:
The candidates taking part in elections are ['Vestal','Torres','Seth','Khan']

Result with both the functions:
The total number of voters are: 4324001
The candidates taking part in elections are [ ]
```

Comment: Close `reader1` and open it again between the functions?

Answer (score 0):

The [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) follows [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) protocol. Since you are sharing the same reader object between both the functions, the reader has already reached the end of the iteration before going to the second function. When the second function fetches the records by calling `next()`on the reader, it is at the end of the list.

You can try one of these approaches:

1. Pass the file path to both functions.

```py
import csv


def total_votes(election_data_file):
    with open(election_data_file) as file1:
        reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
        f1 = [vote1[0] for vote1 in reader1]
        print(f"The total number of voters are: {len(f1) - 1}")


def unique_candidates(election_data_file):
    b = []
    with open(election_data_file) as file1:
        reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
        for cd1 in reader1:
            if cd1[2] == "Candidate":
                None
            elif cd1[2] not in b:
                b.append(cd1[2])
    return f"\nThe candidates taking part in elections are {b}"


election_data_file = 'election_data_1-2.csv'
total_votes(election_data_file)
unique_candidates(election_data_file)
```

2. Load the file data into memory and pass it to the functions. (Will be a problem if the file is too large to fit in memory.)

```py
import csv


def total_votes(election_data):
    f1 = [vote1[0] for vote1 in election_data]
    print(f"The total number of voters are: {len(f1) - 1}")


def unique_candidates(election_data):
    b = []
    for cd1 in election_data:
        if cd1[2] == "Candidate":
            None
        elif cd1[2] not in b:
            b.append(cd1[2])
    return f"\nThe candidates taking part in elections are {b}"


election_data = []
with open('election_data_1-2.csv') as file1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    election_data = list(reader1)

total_votes(election_data)
unique_candidates(election_data)
```